# Example for callIncremental func in PlanarizationLayoutUML [OGDF]

Tags: ogdf

I couldn't find any example to use the callIncremental function in PlanarizationLayoutUML class.

Could you please give me an example about callIncremental function in the PlanarizationLayoutUML.  I've tried to use it, however I think I am missing something because it is not working properly.